# CartoDBのAWS EC2へのインストールについて

Tags: aws

#### やりたいこと

[CartoDB](https://carto.com/) をAWS EC2にインストールして利用したい。
login時に発生するエラーを解消したい。

#### 問題の詳細

以下のWebサイトを参考にEC2にCartoDBのインストールを行った。
http://michaelminn.net/tutorials/carto-aws/

`http://${EC2_PublicIP}:3000/`に遷移し、インストールの過程で設定したuserとpasswordを入力しloginすると以下のmessageが表示され、それ以降の操作ができない状態となった。

```
Missing template public/static/dashboard/index.html with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby]}. 
Searched in: 
* "/home/ubuntu/cartodb/app/views" 
* "/home/ubuntu/cartodb/gears/carto_gears_api/app/views" 
* "/home/ubuntu/cartodb" * "/"

Extracted source (around line #54):           
  def index
    render(file: "public/static/dashboard/index.html", layout: false)
  end
  def show

Rails.root: /home/ubuntu/cartodb

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/admin/visualizations_controller.rb:54:in `index'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:150:in `wrap_in_profiler'
```

お手数ですが、エラーの解消方法をご教示ください。

#### 設定

EC2 インスタンスタイプ：t2.medium
AMI ID：ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-xenial-16.04-amd64-server-20180912 (ami-06c43a7df16e8213c)
セキュリティグループ(インバンウンド)：8080,8181,3000はすべて0.0.0.0/0

#### 参考にしたWebサイト

http://michaelminn.net/tutorials/carto-aws/
https://cartodb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html
https://blog.mylab.jp/posts/2016041101/
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iyIoeOB4x4g

Comment: railsエラーが吐かれているのですね。恐らくログイン後`visualizations_controller#index`のコントローラメソッドを実行され、`public/static/dashboard/index.html`テンプレートをレンダリングするのですが、そのテンプレートが見つからないと言われて怒られているのかと。ただ、`public/static`がそもそも`.gitignore`に書かれておりver管理されてないので、インストールする最中にテンプレートをビルドする処理が抜けているのかもしれません…あくまで憶測です

Comment: `.gitignore`の該当箇所はこれですね　https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb/blob/master/.gitignore#L18